# How do I store variables and do math with them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function Calculator() {
  num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
  num1 = parseInt(num1);
  num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
  num2 = parseInt(num2);

  if (num1 || num2 < 0) {
    number1 = num1 * -1;
    number2 = num2 * -1;
  } else {
    top = number1 % number2;
    div = num1 - top;
    bottom = div / number2;
  }

  document.getElementById('OutputDiv').innerHTML = bottom;
  document.getElementById('OutputDiv2').innerHTML = top + "/" + number2;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='n1' onkeyup='Calculator()' />
<input type='text' id='n2' onkeyup='Calculator()' />
<div id='OutputDiv'></div>
<div id='OutputDiv2'></div>
```

It seems like I can't do math with number1 and number2 and it's giving me `NaN` and `undefined` in `#OutputDiv`. I tried putting number1 and number2 in both of the if and else block and also in outside of those blocks before and it still doesn't work. Still new to JS, I think I'm thinking like python that's why it doesn't work. When I input a negative the result should always pop up positive.

Comment: Where are these variable defined? You are doing `number1 % number2` in the `else` block but assigning values to these variables in the `if` block

Comment: @adiga I tried putting it in both the else block and the if block at the same time before but it still say undefined. I also defining outside of both the if and else block and it still say the same thing. Oh and for the var number I did but I didn't put it in Stackoverflow because you can't put too many codes in Stackoverflow

Comment: bottom is not defined

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd I said I defined it in my own code I didnt put it in Stackoverflow because there is a limit amount of code you can put.

Comment: May I ask what is your objective doing this calculator? I don't quite understand what is your goal in the if/else block.

Comment: This is a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain: 1. What's the **purpose** of this code (ex. *pass in 2 numbers and return the sum*), 2. Provide an example consisting of an input (ex. *2 and 8*), 3. Provide an example of what you expect (ex. *10*), 4. Provide an example of what you actually get whether it be incorrect or an error message (ex. *NaN*). Looking at just the math portion...it makes very little sense. Syntactically, it lacks fundamental things such as declaring variables (I suppose Python handles variables differently)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with this code

```
// By convention only constructors should start with a capital letter.
// Not a show-stopper, but of note.
function Calculator() {
  // These values should be defined ... most likely here with the
  // `var`, `let` or `const` keyword.
  num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
  // Older versions of JavaScript required a `radix` operator for parseInt
  // Many consider it good practice to use anyways today.
  // num1 = parseInt(num1, 10);
  num1 = parseInt(num1);
  num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
  num2 = parseInt(num2);

  // This does not do what you think.
  // Try: if (num1 < 0 || num2 < 0)
  if (num1 || num2 < 0) {
    number1 = num1 * -1;
    number2 = num2 * -1;
  } else {
    top = number1 % number2;
    div = num1 - top;
    bottom = div / number2;
  }



  document.getElementById('OutputDiv').innerHTML = bottom;
  document.getElementById('OutputDiv2').innerHTML = top + "/" + number2;
}
```

Comment: It's still putting a undefined number when i input a negative the output should be positive

Comment: Fixed a typo in my example comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the math with `num1` and `num2` that you have defined earlier in your if block, which is fine. Your error is when you try to do this line `top = number1 % number2;` You haven't defined them beforehand therefore, they are not numbers.

If you execute the if block, you will never execute the else block, and vice versa. You have to define the variables before that if/else block to ensure that you work with *defined* variables and not *not defined* variables.

**Also, I want to mention that your code doesn't really make sense to me. There is more than one thing to fix for it to make sense. You should clarify what is it you are trying to calculate so that we can provide a code that could be way clearer than how it is now.**

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);

var number1 = 0, number2 = 0;
var top = 0, div = 0, bottom = 0;

if (num1 || num2 < 0) {
    number1 = num1 * -1;
    number2 = num2 * -1;
} else {
    top = number1 % number2;
    div = num1 - top;
    bottom = div / number2;
}
```

> As mentionned by Jeremy, make sure that you declare your variables with the keywords `let`, `var` and `const`.

Comment: Good, @pensum, this was the very thing I wanted to tell

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple `<input>` Managed by a Single `<form>`

This is a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) simply for the fact that the question is concerned with negative numbers being passed in by user, but there's obviously more pressing matters to resolve.

- Looking at just the math portion...it makes very little sense.
- Syntactically, it lacks fundamental things such as declaring variables (I suppose Python handles variables differently).

---

### Solution

The following demo involves properties which require the use of a `<form>` tag. It will do the following:

- Bind (or register) the ***input*** event to the `<form>` to call `function calculate()`.
- `calculate()` is a callback function that runs whenever the user types within either `<input>`
- User inputs two numbers: nA and nB
- An Event Object is passed along in order to reference DOM elements and extract their values and display the results

  ```
  calculate(event) {...
  ```
- The sum, difference, product, and quotient will be displayed in four separate `<output>` tags.
- As for the answer to your original question (or technically the statement of your originally perceived problem) :

  > *When I input a negative the result should always pop up positive.*

  Use [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) which returns the absolute value of a given number.

---

**Details are commented in demo**
**References are at the end of post**

#### Demo

```js
/* 
Reference the <form> 
(see References - Obtaining a form element object)
*/
const calc = document.forms.calc;

/*
Register the input event to <form> 
(see References - DOM onevent handlers and HTMLElement: input event)
*/
calc.oninput = calculate;

/*
Pass Event Object 
(see References - Introduction to events)
*/
function calculate(event) {

  /* 
  Reference the tag registered to the Event
  - event.currentTarget 
  (see References - Comparison of Event Targets)
  Collect all of the form controls within <form>
  - .elements property 
  (see References - Elements that are considered form controls) 
  */
  const io = event.currentTarget.elements;

  /*
  Reference the <input> tag
  - io.i1
  Get its current value
  - .value
  Convert value String into a Number
  - parseFloat()
  Get absolute value of result
  - Math.abs()
  Repeat the same process for second <input> tag
  */
  let nA = Math.abs(parseFloat(io.i1.value));
  let nB = Math.abs(parseFloat(io.i2.value));
   
  /*
  Collect all form controls with [name="n1"]
  Collect all form controls with [name="n2"] 
  (see References - HTMLFormControlsCollection)
  */
  const HTMLCollectionA = io.n1;
  const HTMLCollectionB = io.n2;
  
  // Loop through each collection and set their .value to the user <input> values
  for (let i=0; i < HTMLCollectionA.length; i++) {
    HTMLCollectionA[i].value = nA;
    HTMLCollectionB[i].value = nB;
  }
  
  /*
  Assign an expression to each of the specified <output> values
  (see References - Referencing Forms and Form Elements)
  */
  io.o1.value = nA + nB;
  io.o2.value = nA - nB;
  io.o3.value = nA * nB;
  io.o4.value = nA / nB;
  
  // Terminate function
  return false;
}
```

```css
:root {font: 400 3vw/1.1 Consolas}
form {display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content:center;width: 90vw}
label, input, output, b {display:inline-block;}
input, output {text-align:right;}
fieldset {width: 35vw;}
.inputs {width: 75vw}
label {width: 15ch}
```

```html
<form id='calc'>
  <fieldset class='inputs'>
    <legend>Type a number in each field</legend>
    <label><var>nA</var> = </label><input id='i1' type='number' value='0'><br>
    <label><var>nB</var> = </label><input id='i2' type='number' value='0'>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Addition</legend>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Addend: </label><output name='n1'></output><br>
    <b>&plus;&nbsp;</b><label>Addend: </label><output name='n2'></output><br>
    <hr>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Sum: </label><output id='o1'></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Subtraction</legend>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Minuend: </label><output name='n1'></output><br>
    <b>&minus;&nbsp;</b><label>Subtrahend: </label><output name='n2'></output><br>
    <hr>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Difference: </label><output id='o2'></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Multiplication</legend>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Factor: </label><output name='n1'></output><br>
    <b>&times;&nbsp;</b><label>Factor: </label><output name='n2'></output><br>
    <hr>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Product: </label><output id='o3'></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Division</legend>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Dividend: </label><output name='n1'></output><br>
    <b>&divide;&nbsp;</b><label>Divisor: </label><output name='n2'></output><br>
    <hr>
    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><label>Quotient: </label><output id='o4'></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

#### References

- [Referencing Forms and Form Elements](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/references.php)
- [Obtaining a form element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Obtaining_a_form_element_object)
- [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [Elements that are considered form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Elements_that_are_considered_form_controls)
- [Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
- [DOM onevent Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)
- [HTMLElement: input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)
- [Comparison of Event Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets)